# SQL Query-Multiple date ranges

Tags: sql-server, dbvisualizer, sql-query-store

I want to fetch some data from DB by giving multiple date ranges. Example,in February I want to get weekly report from a table in this order Feb 01 to 07, Feb 07 to 14, Feb 14 to 21, Feb 21 to 28 and Feb 28 to Mar 01. In DB the records are stored in a daily wise not in weekly wise. I want to cluster it as weekly wise and calculate sum then show the result. Please help me if you know this case.

For clear cut view, consider 3 tables & its columns.

```
Table A:id,timestamp (comment-data is inserted daily)   
Table B:id,fruits  
Table C:id,fruits_type
```

Result:

```
fruits_type count(id)   timestamp 
apple   3   01-02-2016 to 07-02-2016 
orange  5   01-02-2016 to 07-02-2016 
pineapple   8   01-02-2016 to 07-02-2016 
apple   4   07-02-2016 to 14-02-2016 
orange  5   07-02-2016 to 14-02-2016
```

Conditions:id should match among 3 tables;fetch data by providing group by fruits_type and timestamp should be in weekly wise.

Please help if you know this

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant table(s) structure, some sample data and desired result.

Comment: Are you interested in a general solution for a weekly calculation or just for the specific dates?

Comment: For clear cut view, consider 3 tables & its columns.
Table A:id,timestamp (comment-data is inserted daily)
Table B:id,fruits
Table C:id,fruits_type
Result:
fruits_type count(id) timestamp
apple          3         01-02-2016 to 07-02-2016
orange          5         01-02-2016 to 07-02-2016
pineapple          8         01-02-2016 to 07-02-2016
apple          4         07-02-2016 to 14-02-2016
orange          5         07-02-2016 to 14-02-2016
Conditions:id should match among 3 tables;fetch data by providing group by fruits_type and timestamp should be in weekly wise. Please help if you know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum of all values between two dates you would do it like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Column1)
FROM Table1
WHERE Date1 BETWEEN '2/1/2016' AND Date1 <'2/7/2016'
```

If you want to make it more flexible and have the query get the last week's sum you can use the DATEADD function to lag by one week:

```
SELECT SUM(Column1)
FROM Table1
WHERE Date1 BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -1, GETDATE()) AND Date1 < GETDATE()
```

If you want the result set to include a row for each week, you can use UNION to merge the queries.